# when I receive data from tcp client, I cannot make changes from xaml pages from ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm studying xamarin.forms and wpf. I'm stuck on here :

I have tcp server in my app, when my tcp server received data from clients, my event (Which is in ViewModelBase) is trigger and then it must show data on current xaml page but it is not show. anyone know that how should I bind this event with current xaml page.

What I want is that when Tcp client send me data(it's just string), I want to show this data on screen with DisplayAlert.

If I use button, it works but not I want.

ViewModelBase Class

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IDestructible
{
    protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }
    protected IPageDialogService DialogService { get; private set; }

    public static ProxyServer Client { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ListItems { get; set; }

    private DelegateCommand _eventCommand;
    public DelegateCommand EventCommand
    {
        get { return _eventCommand; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _eventCommand, value); }
    }
    public DelegateCommand DisconnectCommand { get; set; }

    private object _lockObj = new object();

    public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService,IPageDialogService dialogService)
    {
        Client = ProxyServer.GetInstance();

        EventCommand = new DelegateCommand(Client_ListenServer, () => { return true; });
        DisconnectCommand = new DelegateCommand(Disconnect, () => { return true; });

        NavigationService = navigationService;
        DialogService = dialogService;
        ListItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>()
        {
            new Item()
            {
                Id = "0",
                Name = "Android",
                Description = "Android Mobil"
            },
            new Item()
            {
                Id = "1",
                Name = "IOS",
                Description = "IOS Mobil"
            },
              new Item()
            {
                Id = "2",
                Name = "UWP",
                Description = "UWP Mobil + From"
            }
        }; // sample
    }

    private void Client_ListenServer()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("I'm triggered");
        DialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("test title", "message", "OK !", "cancel");
    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {
        Client.Disconnect();
        RemoveEventHandler();
        DialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Status", "Disconnected..", "OK");
    }

    #region NavigationMethods
    public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        RemoveEventHandler();
    }
    public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (Client.ConnectedStatus())
            AddEventHandler();
    }
    public virtual void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters) 
    {
        RemoveEventHandler();
    }

    public virtual void Destroy()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    private void Client_ListenServer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Client_ListenServer(); // this method must show dialogAlert on current page
    }

    public void RemoveEventHandler()
    {
        Client.ListenServer -= Client_ListenServer;
    }
    public void AddEventHandler()
    {
        Client.ListenServer += Client_ListenServer;
    }
}
```

Client_ListenServer method trigger but DisplayAlert not working.

current xaml page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="DataViewer.Views.Login"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="20" Padding="20"> 
            <Entry  Text="{Binding Username}" Placeholder="Username"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="true"/>
            <Button Text="Login" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Command="{Binding AuthorizeCommand}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Secondary" Text="Connect" Command="{Binding ConnectCommand}"/>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Secondary" Text="Disconnect" Command="{Binding DisconnectCommand}" />
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Secondary" Text="Get Data" Command="{Binding EventCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

my app.cs

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/ConnectionPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Login, LoginViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Views.ListView, ListViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Item, ItemViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ConnectionPage>();
        }
    }
```

Android mainActivity Class

```
  [Activity(Label = "DataViewer", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            UserDialogs.Init(this);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
        }

    }

    public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry container)
        {
            // Register any platform specific implementations
        }
    }
```

Comment: My guess; `DisplayAlert` needs to be run on the UI thread. Your button invoke is on it, the tcp listener isn't. Throw a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` (or whatever the Xamarin equivalent is) on there

Comment: I was try that solution with this Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
    DialogService.DisplayAlertAsync(data.Title, data.Message, "OK!", "Cancel");

    Client.SetResponseToDefault();
});

Comment: but also this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
  // whatever UI operation you need goes here
});
```

to force your UI code to execute on the Main (UI) thread from a background thread